# Erasing parts of a bitmap in EaselJS using destination-out compositing

Tags: easeljs

I'm having a bit of difficulty getting some functionality to work. I'm trying to create an eraser and erase parts of an image using easelJS. I've seen other people do this, but only erasing other graphics - and when I try to erase an image, I can't get anything to work. If I wanted to erase a bitmap instead of other graphics, is that possible?

I also tried to use the AlphaMaskFilter, but it's giving me the exact opposite of what I'm looking for (it's masking everything, and only revealing what I paint).

```
var c = createjs, stage, art;
var x, y, listener, color, hue=0;

stage = new c.Stage("test");
var testImg = new c.Bitmap("http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-5.jpg");

art = stage.addChild(testImg, new c.Shape());
art.cache(0,0,600,400);

stage.on("stagemousedown", startDraw, this);

function startDraw(evt) {
    listener = stage.on("stagemousemove", draw, this);
    stage.on("stagemouseup", endDraw, this);
    color = c.Graphics.getHSL(hue+=85, 50, 50);
    x = evt.stageX-0.001; // offset so we draw an initial dot
    y = evt.stageY-0.001;
    draw(evt); // draw the initial dot
}

function draw(evt) {
    art.graphics.ss(20,1).s(color).mt(x,y).lt(evt.stageX, evt.stageY);

    // the composite operation is the secret sauce.
    // we'll either draw or erase what the user drew.
    art.updateCache(erase.checked ? "destination-out" : "source-over");

    art.graphics.clear();
    x = evt.stageX;
    y = evt.stageY;
    stage.update();
}

function endDraw(evt) {
    stage.off("stagemousemove", listener);
    evt.remove();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/17xec9y5/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example is only affecting the Shape instance that you have cached. When you use multiple arguments in `addChild()`, it returns the last added item, so in your sample, the `art` variable just references the shape. So the image is just below the "painted area" that you are drawing to.

To fix this, create and cache a container instead. A few minor additions:

1. Once the image loads, update the cache one time (to apply the image).
2. Then remove the image so it is no longer applied every time you update the cache while drawing.

That's it!

Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/17xec9y5/9/

Relevant Code:

```
// Listen for the image load
testImg.image.onload = function() {
    cont.updateCache("source-over"); // Update cache once
    cont.removeChild(testImg); // Remove image

    stage.update(); // Draw the stage to see the image
}

// Create a sub-container that will hold the art and image 
var cont = stage.addChild(new c.Container());
art = new c.Shape(); // Art is just the shape
cont.cache(0,0,600,400); // Cache the container instead
cont.addChild(testImg, art);

// Then, later update the container's cache (instead of the art)
cont.updateCache(erase.checked ? "destination-out" : "source-over");
```

Comment: It's embarrassing that I didn't think of this. Thanks Lanny! 

By the way, I've really not had to look at the documentation for EaselJS - and have building it pretty much like I would with AS3. There's been a few exceptions to that rule, but for the most part, the learning curve is very minimal. That's a really hard thing to achieve and deserves to be mentioned. Kudos!

Comment: @Lanny sorry for resurrecting this old post, but in your example fiddle, how would I go about "resetting" the stage to its original state (i.e. with the `testImg` rendered and untouched by any drawing/erasing)?

Comment: You can add the testImg again, update the cache, remove it, and it will essentially be reset: http://jsfiddle.net/17xec9y5/28/